# How do you create a foreign key relationship in EF Core to a column that isn't the primary key but already has a foreign key relationship?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

[image: Simple DB Schema]

We've migrated away from using an incrementing ID column on the `User` table to generating the IDs in the `Resource` table and then a foreign key relationship to it.

We use the Code-First EF approach to generate migration scripts and the subsequent DB schema. At the moment we're trying to create a foreign key relationship between `User Invite` and `User` on the `ResourceId`. Not matter which way I try this, it ends up with EF creating a shadow foreign key property called `ResourceId1` on the `User` table.

```
The foreign key property 'User.ResourceId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'ResourceId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type.
```

You can create this kind of foreign key relationship inside SSMS without issue, but I can't find a way to do it via code-first.

**Definitions**

```
public class Resource
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ResourceId { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

```
public class UserInvite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserResourceId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserResourceId")]
    public User? User { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Fluent API**

Tried the following (separately)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserInvite>()
    .HasOne(ui => ui.User)
    .WithMany()
    .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.ResourceId);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany<UserInvite>()
    .WithOne(ui => ui.User)
    .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.ResourceId);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany<UserInvite>()
    .WithOne(ui => ui.User)
    .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.ResourceId)
    .HasForeignKey(ui => ui.UserResourceId);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserInvite>()
    .HasOne(ui => ui.User)
    .WithMany()
    .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.ResourceId)
    .HasForeignKey(ui => ui.UserResourceId);
```

---

**Modify Migration Script**

Modifying the migration script ends up confusing EF when you attempt insert a record, I'm guessing it's expecting the `User.Id` column to be the foreign key principal column.

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserResourceId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserResourceId))]
    public User? User { get; set; }
}
```

`principalColumn` has been changed from `Id` to `ResourceId`.

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "UserInvite",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
        UserResourceId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: true)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Tests", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Tests_Users_UserResourceId",
            column: x => x.UserResourceId,
            principalTable: "Users",
            principalColumn: "ResourceId");
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

It seemed like explicitly defining the relationship between Resource and User was necessary for this to work.  Without that defined, EF wanted to create ResourceId1 to represent the second relationship on User.ResourceId.

This works

```
public class Resource
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ResourceId { get; set; }
  public Resource Resource { get; set; } = default!;
}
public class UserInvite
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int? UserResourceId { get; set; }
  public User? User { get; set; }
}
public class UserInviteConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<UserInvite>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserInvite> builder)
  {
    builder.HasOne(x => x.User)
      .WithMany()
      .HasPrincipalKey(x => x.ResourceId)
      .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserResourceId);
  }
}
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
  {
    builder.HasOne(x => x.Resource)
      .WithOne()
      .HasForeignKey<User>(x => x.ResourceId);
  }
}
```

This generates the following SQL script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Resource] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Resource] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ResourceId] int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_User_ResourceId] UNIQUE ([ResourceId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Resource_ResourceId] FOREIGN KEY ([ResourceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Resource] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInvite] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserResourceId] int NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInvite] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserInvite_User_UserResourceId] FOREIGN KEY ([UserResourceId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([ResourceId])
);
GO

CREATE INDEX [IX_UserInvite_UserResourceId] ON [dbo].[UserInvite] ([UserResourceId]);
GO
```

1. EF automatically creates the Unique Constraint on User.ResourceId, which is required for it to be key column for UserInvite.UserResourceId
2. Since each Resource can only be associated to a single User, that relationship is a 1:1.
3. EF automatically named the unique constraint for the principal key with an AK prefix, indicating that constraint is used to enforce an Alternate Key.

FYI: Although the relationship can be configured from either side, I'm a big proponent of configuring the relationship on the entity that contains the FK column.  I find it makes the configurations more intuitive and reduces the bloat in the PK configuration for frequently referenced entities.

**/Update**

---

Just to make sure I'm understanding... you want to link UserInvite.UserResourceId to the non-key column ResourceId in the User table.  User has a PK of Id.  User.ResourceId is a FK reference to another table (Resource?) in which ResourceId is the PK.  Posting your definitions for all three classes would have been helpful.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserInvite>()
.HasOne(ui => ui.User)
.WithMany(u => u.UserInvites)
.HasPrinicipalKey<User>(u => u.ResourceId)
.HasForeignKey<UserInvite>(ui => ui.UserResourceId);
```

Putting the < Type > in the clause explicitly tells EF which entity has the key.  Using HasPrincipalKey/HasForeignKey without the explicit type requires EF to assume where the property exists.  If it guesses the wrong side and can't find the field, it will create one.

Also note that when EF creates a numbered shadow property, it sees the original field but "knows" it can't use it for the relationship, so it creates a new field suffixed with a number.  This usually happens when there is a navigation property `List<UserInvite> UserInvites` , but the relationship was defined without the property... `.WithMany()` instead of `.WithMany(x=>x.UserInvites)`.

Since your configuration created `User.ResourceId1`, you may want to validate your model as EF is seeing a second relationship for `User.ResourceId`.  I suspect that this is happening because your configuration did not include the HasForeignKey clause.  EF saw that ResourceId already existed in the model, but it is not defined as the FK, so it created `ResourceId1` to represent the FK.

FYI: User.ResourceId must be unique to be used as a principal key.  You may want to add an explicit unique constraint.  I'm not sure if EF does that automatically.

Comment: I've updated the post with the definitions, but they don't show much more than the image at the top. Also updated the fluent API configuration I've tried. `HasPrinicipalKey` & `HasForeignKey` don't accept generic parameters, they're derived from the `HasMany` & `WithOne`. Even with adding in the `HasForeignKey`, it still results in creating the shadow property.

Comment: EF Core seems to be complaining because there's already a FK relationship on `User.ResourceId` to `Resource.Id`, even though it's OK to also have a FK relationship from`UserInvite.UserResourceId` to `User.ResourceId`.

Comment: Adding your full class definitions helped.  I've updated my answer.